# spring-boot - turn off console logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

Want to configure a spring-boot (1.3.5) application to send log-output only to a file -- turn off the console.

It looks very easy, according to the docs:
[howto-logging.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) -- section 
  **§ 72.1.1 Configure logback for file only output**

But I just cannot get this to work -- it still logs **both** to file **and** console, whatever I try. 
Been googling for hours, but cannot find any suggestion that actually works.

Any clue what the issue might be?

***EDIT***: Please **dont** mark this as "duplicate" -- I have read them all -- and none of the suggested solutions work here.

Comment: Would be good to know how your POM is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally --- I found the bug... 
This is a multi-module build, and turned out in one sub-module, there was also a **logback.xml**, that apparently took priority over the **logback-spring.xml** that I was fiddling with. When I excluded the other file from the build, it finally worked as expected. Phew....

Answer (score 3):

Setting `logging.pattern.console=` (value is left blank) in application.properties, works for me.

Comment: @prashanth-g this just writes "false" for every log line in console!

Comment: worked as charm

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `logback.xml` in your classpath root with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myApp.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This would write all logs to the `myApp.log` file. Checkout [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) for more detailed discussion.

Comment: As I wrote, I sure *have* read the darn docs, but it just refuses to work! :) --- anyways, I realize I will have to set up a demo/poc on this, and will push to github, if I can demonstrate it --- I'll be back...

Answer (score 1):

Having it set up, these are the steps I've followed:

Create a demo Spring Boot web project with this pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As it's said [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-logging), the logging starter is not necessary because it's already included in the web starter. Let's create a `@Service` with some [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org) logging (that's not necessary at all):

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

    public MyService() {
        logger.info("Created!");
    }

}
```

Then, we create a logback-spring.xml file, only configuring the file appender and not the one for the console, as the documentation suggests. Save it in the *src/main/resources* folder, the one Maven places at the root of the classpath:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="target/spring.log" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

When project starts, the initial log is shown in console but no more output is shown as it gets redirected to the target/spring.log file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console=:
  level
    root=OFF
```